# how to get the last message grouped as per user name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to group the messages the user has received by the sender name. I want to display the last message in each chat, much like in whatsapp.

I tried using match and group. I found a solution recommending using `joins($lookup)`, but finally realized using match and group might be sufficient.

userId I am getting from the route

```js
     Message.aggregate(
              [
                { $match: { $or: [{ 'from.userId': userId }, { 'to.userId': userId }] } },
                // { $project: {...FIELDS}}, ///what to use here
                { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
                {
                  $group: {
                    "_id": {
                      'fromuserId': userId,//confusion here
                      // 'toUserId': userId,
                      // 'to.user'
                    },
                    // 'userId': { $first: '$from' },
                    // 'userId': { $first: '$to' },
                    msg: { $first: '$msg' },
                    timestamp: { $first: '$timestamp' }
                  }
                }
              ]
            ).exec((err, results) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log('err===>', err);
              }
              console.log('results|||', results)
            })
```

my schema is this :

```js
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      to: {
        userId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,// to be sent from client side 
          ref: "User",
          required: true
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
        },
        pictureUrl: {
          type: String,
        }
      },
      from: {
        userId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,// to be sent from server side 
          ref: "User",
          required: true
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
        },
        pictureUrl: {
          type: String,
        }
      },
      message: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
      {
        timestamps: true
      }
    );
```

I am getting an empty array as output. I need to know how to use the `id` in `$group`. also how to use `to.userId` or `from.userId` in the `id`. it's not allowing dot (`.`) inside `id`.

Comment: hey, inside `$group` , in the place of `_id` have you tried passing  `"_id": {
     'fromuserId': "$from.userId",
     'toUserId': '$to.user',
    }`

Comment: still getting an empty array

Comment: may be to debug, lets keep `_id:userId` and check, if any data is coming.